# insert data to mysql with php array and class oop?

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have some code:

```
function save_article() {
        $data = array(
                'post_id' => NULL,
                'post_author' => 1,
                'post_cat' => $this->var->post('category'),
                'post_title' => $this->var->post('title'),
                'post_content' => $this->var->post('content'),
                'post_date' => null,
                'post_thumb' => $this->var->post('thumbnail'),
                'post_type' => 'tutorial',
                'post_hits' => 0
        );
        $this->db->insert($data, "tbl_posts");
}
```

This function is part of the `$this->db` object class

```
public function insert($data, $tbl) {
        $query = "insert into ".$tbl." set";
        foreach ($data as $field => $value) {
                $query .= $field."=". mysql_real_escape_string($value) .",";
        }
        $query = rtrim($query, ",");
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        return $result;
}
```

But for some reason the data is not saving in the database.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because StackOverflow is not a crowd-sourced debugging tool.

Answer (score 0):

Have you even bothered doing an `echo $query` to see if you're building the query correctly? How about `var_dump($result)` to see if you're getting a boolean false, which'd indicate failure? I'm guessing not, because otherwise you'd see you're missing quotes around ALL of your inserted values:

This:

```
            $query .= $field."=". mysql_real_escape_string($value) .",";
```

Is going to generate something like

```
   ... somefield=SOMEVALUE
```

But since SOMEVALUE is not quoted, it's going to be interepreted as a non-existing field.

You need:

```
            $query .= $field."='". mysql_real_escape_string($value) ."',";
                               ^---                                   ^--
```

as a bare minimum "fix" for your problem.

Your "For some reason..." is YOU. you have FAILED to check if the query was correctly built, and you have FAILED to check if the query call even succeeded. Even a bare bones:

$result= mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

would have helped you fix this.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $query = "insert into ".$tbl." set";
```

after set you missing a space do this

```
$query = "insert into ".$tbl." set ";
```

and in foreach you missed the single quote try this

```
foreach ($data as $field => $value) {
            $query .= $field."='". mysql_real_escape_string($value) ."',";
    }
```